# C#: Find a key without knowing where it is

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I'd like to preface this by highlighting that I am fairly new to C#.

I'm trying to make a program to find and edit a registry value in order to disable CPU core parking using this method: [Registry Edit](http://forum.cakewalk.com/Windows-7-amp-Core-Parking-a-better-way-to-Turn-It-OFF-m1861804.aspx)

The issue is that I know the start of the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings\
```

But not the Next part but I know the segment after that:

```
0cc5b647-c1df-4637-891a-dec35c318583
```

So if it looks like this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings\<UNKNOWN>\0cc5b647-c1df-4637-891a-dec35c318583
```

How do I find the  using Registry and Registrykey? I tried looping through all subkeys and I just get an exception because all I get back is null.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can you place the code which you have written down to loop through registry ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion for finding `SubKey`.

```
private RegistryKey SearchSubKey(RegistryKey Key,String KeyName)
{
    foreach (String subKey in Key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        RegistryKey key1 = Key.OpenSubKey( subKey);

        if (subKey.ToUpper() == KeyName.ToUpper())
            return key1;
        else
        {
            RegistryKey mReturn = SearchSubKey(key1, KeyName);
            if (mReturn != null)
                return mReturn;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Call this function as

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings\");
RegistryKey SubKey = SearchSubKey(key, "0cc5b647-c1df-4637-891a-dec35c318583");
```

This function search through all sub keys in main key recursively. If you want to search up to particular level then you have to add that logic in function.

Comment: This was perfect and exactly what I was looking for. It worked 100%!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to mention the Registry key name in a proper fashion. Here is the piece of code which brings out the output :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion");
        foreach (var v in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\" + v);
            foreach ( var v1 in key1.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (v1 == "{00EC8ABC-3C5A-40F8-A8CB-E7DCD5ABFA05}")
                Console.WriteLine(key1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this works.